# How do I resize a partition on an img file?

Tags: linux, partitioning, disk-image, puppylinux, img

I have a puppy linux img that is 8gb but I need it to fit on a 6gb drive. How do I resize the ext2 partition on the img?

Comment: This is tricky and could cause errors and problems.  You need to first shrink the ext2 filesystem (using, for example resize2fs), then resize the partition.  You may want to shrink the filesystem to say 5.5 gigs, then resize the partition to 6 gigs, then grow the filesystem back up to 6 gigs.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://sirlagz.net/2012/06/20/how-to-resize-partitions-on-an-image-file/